# The getter 'outlineVariant' isn't defined for the class 'Scheme'

Tags: flutter, flutter3.7

Earlier, I was using `flutter 3.4`, and My project compiled successfully. Recently, We've migrated to `flutter 3.7` and I am getting the below error.

```
error: [+1994 ms] ../../../../../../development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/color_scheme.dart:237:54: Error: The getter 'outlineVariant' isn't defined for the class 'Scheme'.
```

Comment: Could you run `flutter clean`, tell us your Gradle version as well as add your `flutter doctor` output?

Comment: Thanks!! The issue happens due to the latest flutter version upgrade. I fixed the issue by downgrading the flutter version to 3.4 instead of 3.7 Anyway thanks!!

Comment: If you take a look at the release notes how ever it suggests that it should be included I think: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/sdk/release-notes/release-notes-3.7.0

Comment: Yes, It's already included in the release note

Comment: I think it should work then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue happens due to the latest flutter version upgrade. I fixed the issue by downgrading the flutter version to `flutter 3.4` instead of `flutter 3.7`

Answer (score 1):

For me doing `flutter clean` and then `flutter pub get` solved the problem.

Comment: This + pod install in ios folder fixed for me. No need to downgrade